# Should I update my fedora encrypted system?

Tags: encryption, sha-256, sha-1

I have installed my Fedora Workstation version 23 using native disk encryption. Since it, I am upgrading it using dnf system-upgrade plugin. Today, I have fedora 32. Some time ago, I’ve discovered about SHA1 is now discontinued.

Reading the cryptsetup luksDump of my encrypted system, I can see it was installed using SHA1:

```
Version: 1
Cipher name: aes
Cipher mode: xts-plain64
Hash spec: sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits: 512
```

My password length has more than 70 characters. But, should I reinstall the full system to update my hash encryption ?
I am really unsafe for keeping SHA1 ?

Comment: Get rid of SHA-1 and this is rather easy to migrate with a new key slot [Unix & Linux.SE : How to change the hash-spec and iter-time of an existing dm-crypt LUKS device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101343/70178)

Comment: Dear kelalaka, it is really safe to do ? Will my files be lost ? I mean, I have a full whole encrypted disk and not just a container.

Comment: You create a new key slot and test with it then you can remove the old one. Like many encrypted filesystem Luks also support multiple keys to access the files. Of course, we don't take responsibility!

Comment: I've made a test. First, created the container. Then, tried to change the hash to another than used. It has worked, the hash was changed. And the container opens with same password correctly, keeping files without any file or content lost.

Comment: What is what expected. Note 1: you can save the key slots, too. Note 2: this is a bit off-topic here.

Comment: I've performed the same test for regular container and for attached header container. Both worked correctly. But, I am not sure to do it in my main system. Do I have to power off my system first and then run a LiveCD to do it with system unmounted ??

Comment: I've performed the same test for the backuped header of my encrypted system. I've tried to SHA256 and to SHA512. Iterations has increased too significant in SHA512 ! I can't believe, I am using the old hash for more than 7 years.